# Using excel vba to change the value of a dropdown menu on a website2

Tags: html, excel, vba

How i can choose a specific value using excel vba?

```
    <div class="drpSirketler">
    <select class="selectBox homepage selectSirketler" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px">
    <option selected="selected" value="default">Şirket Seçiniz</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="-1">Tüm Finansal Tablolar</option>
    <option value="1626">ACISELSAN ACIPAYAM SELÜLOZ SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.</option>
    <option value="831">ADANA ÇİMENTO SANAYİİ T.A.Ş.</option>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look at - [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and research. Have you looked at other vba answers for inspiration like http://stackoverflow.com/a/19285535/4606130 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/17818903/4606130? What does the 2 in your title mean - please proof read before posting? It will make people more willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

Where `doc` is the HTMLdocument object:

```
doc.GetElementsByClassName("selectBox homepage selectSirketler")(0).Value = "default"
```

should produce the "Şirket Seçiniz" value.

---

If there are other elements in the document with the same class name, then you will have to iterate through the collection of those tags and test each one.

Comment: Thank you very much Macro Man !